# ListView with complex ViewModel structure

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

For a project I have a quite complicated viewModel structure.

Please note that I omitted the "NotifyOfPropertyChange" calls in the setters!

```
public class EntityViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<PlatformViewModel> Platforms;
}

public class PlatformViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<UnitViewModel> Units;
}

public class UnitViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ModuleViewModel> Units;

    public string UnitName { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string Version { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to visualize it in a List, like this here (just to make the wanted result more clear)

[image: Visualisation of ViewModels]

where black are the platforms, greens the units and orange the modules.

Have tried with ListView, but without success. Never get a single element displayed.

**So the question is:**

- What is the best way to get to that kind of visualisation?
- Would ListView be a good choice?
- Is there a good example anywhere around that I cannot find?

Comment: Should be doable with ListView. Maybe even pure ItemsControl is better. Can you show your xaml?

Comment: Many excuses that I returned that late to the question! The XAML part is no longer an issue I think ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to get you started, will need to further customize layout.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Platforms}" >
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
               <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Units}">
                          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                               <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Units}">
                                          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl>
                                    </Border>
                                   </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </Border>
                      </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: First of all: Please excuse me for returning that late here! And second: Wonderful! Workes immediatelly after C&P it!

Comment: @MareInfinitus glad to help. Maybe a green check mark on answer is in order :)

Comment: Probably have to change the innermost ItemsControl to a horizontal stackpanel, but should be not a big problem. Thank you so much! Glad that I can give the "green check" ;)

Comment: Okay, getting it horizontal is not that easy... but I will try

Comment: You don't have to replace ItemsControl with StackPanel, you can only change ItemsControl.ItemsPanel to a different panel, so you can still use ItemTemplate, items will have your desired layout and the same template. Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if each element is selectable, or if they are uniformly sized horizontally, but if so you should be able to model this with nested `ItemsControl`.

Set the `ItemsPanel` to a `UniformGrid` with `Rows="1"` for the `Unit` `ItemsControl`, and the other `ItemsControl`'s default `ItemsPanel` of vertical `StackPanel`s should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! This can be very helpful for the inner itemscontrols!

Comment: Have used the UniformGrid and it looks exactly like I want it. Is there a way that I can virtualize it? I have lots of UIElements in that view, i gets kind of slow (loading time even on my machine above 1 second). Think that there are about 5000 elements right now (counting textboxes, grids, itemscontrols and that)